# "StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer()" get a null value in Android

Tags: java, android, stringbuffer

I use the code below which in my http get request,but what I get from return is a null.I don't know why.

```
  public static String getResponseFromGetUrl(String url) throws Exception {

               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();


                try {
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

                    String inputLine = "";

                    if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

                        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(httpResponse
                                .getEntity().getContent());
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(is);
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

                            sb.append(inputLine);
                        }

                        in.close();

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "net_error";         
                } finally {
                    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                }

                return sb.toString();

   }
```

And what I have use the function is

```
  String json_str = HttpUtils.getResponseFromGetUrl("www.xxx.com/start");
   if ((json_str == null)) Log.d("Chen", "lastestTimestap----" + "json_str == null");
```

And sometimes the Log will be printed.Not always,in fact like 1%.But I don't know why it caused.

Comment: Can we see more code ? How do you determine it's null ?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally did things like `sb.append("null");`.

Comment: The shown method `getResponseFromGetUrl` cannot return `null` under any circumstances. Either you aren't showing the real code in your question or the function calling it in fact calls a different method (e.g. in a different class).

Comment: @Codo It's real my whole code.I have tried this code It also occur the probem.

Comment: So if both the code for `getResponseFromGetUrl` and for the code calling it are real, then either a different method gets called (check the `import` statement) or the log message is coming for a different location (have you copied the log message somewhere else and forgotten to change the message?).

Answer (score 3):

This code will not produce a "null".  There must be more code you are not showing.

If this is all the code you have I suggest you remove the StringBuffer and replace it with

```
return "";
```

More likely you have forgetten to mention some code which is doing something like

```
Object o = null;

sb.append(o); // appears as "null"
```

EDIT: Based on your update, I would have to assume you are reading a line like "null"

It is highly unlikely you want to discard the newline between each line.  I suggest either you append("\n") as well or just record all the text you get without regard for new lines.

BTW Please don't use StringBuffer as its replacement StringBuilder has been around for almost ten years.  There is a common misconception that using StringBuffer helps with multi-threading but more often it results in incorrect code because it is very harder, if not impossible to use StringBuffer correctly in a multi-threaded context

Comment: He doesnt mention a NullPointerException anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But in fact I did not do those.So I'm so puzzle

Comment: @MarshalChen Unless you print out exactly what you are getting as input, how do you know for sure?

Comment: I'm not sure what the input is,but in my opinion the stringbuffer could be "" ,but can't be null as I have already create it

Comment: @MarshalChen if it were `null` you would see a NullPointerException.  To see `null` you must have this in the text i.e. it is `"null"` not `null`

Comment: String json_str = HttpUtils.getResponseFromGetUrl("www.xxx.com/start");
   if ((json_str == null)) Log.d("Chen", "lastestTimestap----" + "json_str == null");  I used it like this which I have already edited.So I think it should be null not "null".It doesn't appear often,but sometimes

Comment: If the machine is lack of memory ,would this happen?

Comment: StringBuffer.toString() will never return a `null` unless there is a very serious bug in your JVM.

Comment: If you are out of memory, you will get an OutOfMemoryError or in extreme cases, the JVM will crash e.g. if you run out swap space. You won't get a `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Although I use Android ,I don't think such simple process could cause serious bug in delvik.But in fact,it caused .(json_str == null)